# creating my own iterator for generic data type

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I can't understand why my code doesn't compile.

```
template<class Priority,class T> class PriorityQueue {
public:
  class Iterator;
  //some methods
  Iterator begin() const;
  Iterator end() const;
};
```

and then in the Iterator class:

```
template<class Priority,class T>
class PriorityQueue<Priority,T>::Iterator {
   //implement ctor,operator++,==etc.
```

Almost all the 84-errors I get are about these functions:

```
template<class Priority,class T>
Iterator<Priority,T> PriorityQueue<Priority,T>::begin() const{
    return Iterator<Priority,T>(firstNode);
}
template<class Priority,class T>
Iterator<Priority,T> PriorityQueue<Priority,T>::end() const{
    return Iterator<Priority,T>(nullptr);
}
```

The error is: Error 2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int. And: Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int and: Error    1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'.
All regarding the method begin() and end() (in their first line Iterator PriorityQueue::begin()).
EDIT: I tried using typename but it didn't help.

Comment: `class Iterator;` is a forward declaration you can't declare classes and then define them.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the right way of doing this?

Comment: Easiest way is just putting the definition of `Iterator` (i.e. `class Iterator { ... };`) where you currently have the declaration (*inside* `PriorityQueue`).

Comment: I copied all class Iterator inside PQ, but now that all class Iterator is public, anyone can use its ctor right? isn't that a bad thing?

Comment: Post your full code (stripped down to a minimal example that reproduces the problem). As it is, any answers will be based on guessing about the exact form of your code and the problems that it could contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```
template<class Priority, class T> class PriorityQueue {
  class Iterator {
    //implement ctor,operator++,==etc.
  };

public:
  typedef Iterator iterator;
  //some methods//implement ctor,operator++,==etc.
  Iterator begin() const;
  Iterator end() const;
};

template<class Priority,class T>
typename PriorityQueue<Priority, T>::iterator 
PriorityQueue<Priority,T>::begin() const    {
    return Iterator(); // return right staff
}

template<class Priority,class T>
typename PriorityQueue<Priority, T>::iterator
PriorityQueue<Priority,T>::end() const{
    return Iterator(); // return right staff
}
```

- I recommend you declare/define your `Iterator` `private`, and provide access via a `typedef`, much like what STL does.

### [DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a271f9a515472a6d)